# "Waiting for X server to begin accepting connections" infinite loop

Tags: archlinux, xserver

I installed an Archlinux distribution, and I am trying to install xOrg. 
I installed xorg-server xorg-xinit and xorg-server-utils.
I also installed xf86-video-nouveau because I have a 960M from Nvidia.

To test it :

```
echo "xterm && sleep 10" > .xinitrc
```

And I run startx. I got this message

```
Waiting for X server to begin accepting connections
```

And after 2-3 minutes, I got :

Unable to connect to X server: connection refused.

Why the connection is refused ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Are `~/.xinitrc` and `~/.xsession` executable (they should be)?  That would look like the kind of issue you may be facing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never answered. But I finally managed to get it working.

I was able to run it by blacklisting nouveau drivers.

To test, at grub boot, press e on the line of your linux distribution.

You should see something like:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-33-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=32290445-e978-4a43-b6d9-27f9e943b3a6 ro  quiet nouveau.modeset=0 splash $vt_handoff
```

Just add `nouveau.modeset=0` between `quiet`and `splash` (pretty sure it's the same as if you write it down at the end of the line but I am 100% sure it's working the way I did).

Press F10 to boot with this configuration. It should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: As obscure as this question may seem, I was also facing the same problem and this solved it. Thanks!